# Android: Unable to implement on click listener for image view in list view

Tags: android

I have got a list view of Lockers with image as well.

In each row of the list view, there is a picture and data:

I have **OnItemClickListener** on this list view.

I have read up on many stackoverflow sites but am still unsure as to how to perform:
Click the ImageView launch MapsActivity, otherwise click anywhere else on ListItem launch StopsScheduleActivity.

I am unsure of how to implement an onclick listener for my image solely based on my code:

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Used to make the URL to call for JSON data
String yahooURLFirst = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?

 q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22";
String yahooURLSecond = 

 "%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
String stockSymbol = "MSFT";

// Will hold the values I pull from the JSON

static String stockDaysLow = "";
static String stockDaysHigh = "";
static String stockYearLow = "";
static String stockYearHigh = "";
static String stockLastPrice = "";
static String stockChange = "";
static String stockDailyPriceRange = "";

// Array of strings storing country names
String[] countries = new String[] { "India", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka",
        "China", "Bangladesh", "Nepal", "Afghanistan", "North Korea",
        "South Korea", "Japan" };

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
int[] flags = new int[] { R.drawable.india, R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal, R.drawable.afghanistan, R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea, R.drawable.japan };

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] currency = new String[] { "SIS", "SOE/SOSS", "SOA/SOL", "LKCSB",
        "Bangladeshi Taka", "Nepalese Rupee", "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won", "South Korean Won", "Japanese Yen" };

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] size = new String[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small",
        "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small" };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Creates the window used for the UI
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    // Create the YQL query
    final String yqlURL = yahooURLFirst + stockSymbol + yahooURLSecond;

    // final String yqlURL2
    // ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?

              q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%
            20in%20(%22msft%22)&format=json&env=
            store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";


    new MyAsyncTask().execute(yqlURL);
     }
```

**MyAsyncTask** class

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

    @Override
    // protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // HTTP Client that supports streaming uploads and downloads
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                new BasicHttpParams());

        // Define that I want to use the POST method to grab data from
        // the provided URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);

        // Web service used is defined
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // Used to read data from the URL
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        // Will hold the whole all the data gathered from the URL
        String result = null;

        try {

            // Get a response if any from the web service
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            // Get the main content from the URL
            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            // JSON is UTF-8 by default
            // BufferedReader reads data from the InputStream until the
            // Buffer is full
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),   
                              8);

            // Will store the data
            StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            // Read in the data from the Buffer until nothing is left
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                // Add data from the buffer to the StringBuilder
                theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Store the complete data in result
            result = theStringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            // Close the InputStream when you're done with it
            try {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        // Holds Key Value pairs from a JSON source
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            // Print out all the data read in
            // Log.v("JSONParser RESULT ", result);

            // Get the root JSONObject
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            // Get the JSON object named query
            JSONObject queryJSONObject = 

                         jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");


            JSONObject resultsJSONObject = queryJSONObject
                    .getJSONObject("results");


            JSONObject quoteJSONObject = resultsJSONObject
                    .getJSONObject("quote");

            // Get the JSON Strings in the quote object
            stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("symbol");
            stockDaysLow = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysLow");
            stockDaysHigh = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysHigh");
            stockYearLow = quoteJSONObject.getString("YearLow");
            stockYearHigh = quoteJSONObject.getString("YearHigh");
            stockLastPrice = quoteJSONObject
                    .getString("LastTradePriceOnly");
            stockChange = quoteJSONObject.getString("Change");
            stockDailyPriceRange =    quoteJSONObject.getString
                            ("DaysRange");

            returnList.add(stockSymbol);
            returnList.add(stockDaysLow);
            returnList.add(stockDaysHigh);
            returnList.add(stockYearLow);
            returnList.add(stockYearHigh);
            returnList.add(stockLastPrice);
            returnList.add(stockChange);
            returnList.add(stockDailyPriceRange);
            returnList.add(stockDaysHigh);
            returnList.add(stockDaysHigh);

            // EXTRA STUFF THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THE PROGRAM

            Log.v("SYMBOL ", stockSymbol);
            Log.v("Days Low ", stockDaysLow);
            Log.v("Days High ", stockDaysHigh);
            Log.v("stockYearLow ", stockYearLow);
            Log.v("stockYearHigh ", stockYearHigh);
            Log.v("stockLastPrice ", stockLastPrice);
            Log.v("stockChange ", stockChange);
            Log.v("stockDailyPriceRange ", stockDailyPriceRange);

            // GET ARRAY DATA
            JSONArray queryArray = quoteJSONObject.names();

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < queryArray.length(); i++) {
                list.add(queryArray.getString(i));
            }

            for (String item : list) {

                Log.v("JSON ARRAY ITEMS ", item);

            }
            // END OF GET ARRAY DATA

            // Gets the first item in the JSONObject
            JSONArray objectArray = resultsJSONObject.names();

            // Prints out that first item in the JSONObject
            Log.v("JSON NEXT NODE ", objectArray.getString(0));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return result;
        return returnList;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> returnList) {

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 

                     String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // hm.put("txt", "Locker No : " + resultList.get(i));
            hm.put("txt", "Locker No : " + i);
            hm.put("cur", "Location : " + returnList.get(i));
            hm.put("size", "Size : " + size[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag", "txt", "cur", "size" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.txt, R.id.cur, R.id.size };

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
                R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.androidlist);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 

                       AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "You Clicked at " + size[+position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });


    }

}

     }
```

Layout **main2.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/butt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/button" >
 </Button>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/androidlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/butt1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Layout  **listview_layout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Please help, I have been looking around answers but unable to find

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution is what you need.

An Interface **OnImageClickListener**

```
public interface OnImageClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, Object data); // Object data [Optional]
}
```

On your **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnImageClickListener {
    //... Your code

    public void inSomeMethod() {
        // Assume that you create an Adapter here.
        new SimpleAdapter(this, ....).execute(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, Object data) {
        // Handle image click here
    }
}
```

On your **Adapter**

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Param, Progress, Result> {
    private OnImageClickListener mListener;
    public SimpleAdapter(OnImageClickListener listener, ...) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public View getView(....) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_img_view);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLisnter{ // I am not sure OnClickListener because I'm using notepad to write this code.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onClick(v, dataIfYouWantToAttach);
             }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi do I need to create a new SimpleAdapter.java class, because I did not do so previously

Comment: You can see more: https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply "onclicklistner" on imageview in adapter class and apply same things on other part of listview..try this it may be solve your problem